# Alfresco : Assigning the next tasks to specific users

Tags: java, alfresco

I need to assign the next two tasks in a workflow to specific users of  specific groups, on for each, in the initial task. How can that be done ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a process variable of type ActivitiScriptNode, set up a new property on some UserTask of type cm:person ....

Setup a Listener on that task to take the value of that property to the process var

On the user task you which to be dynamically assigned to a custom user place this tag:

```
<humanPerformer>
                <resourceAssignmentExpression>
                    <formalExpression>${activitiScriptNodeVar.properties.userName}</formalExpression>
                </resourceAssignmentExpression>
</humanPerformer>
```

Several of the OOTB workflows can be a good example for that. Check this one for example: https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/extension/activiti-adhoc-timer.bpmn20.xml.sample